# Android SQLite and PHP Mysql Database sync giving error 500 on web server

Tags: php, android, mysql, database, sqlite

I have been trying to make a SQLite - MySQL database sync code to work. The code is adapted from a tutorial I got here - [How to sync SQLite on Android to MySQL DB](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-sqlite-on-android-to-mysql-db/). Well, so far so good but when it came to the data synchronisation, I get an error 500 response; both on my server and the android toast response. I have tried posting data from the web and the result  is a success (the data is saved on the MySQL database). Why would it give an error 500. Below is the error displayed by logcat and attached is  a screenshot of my web server console.[image: server error console]

```
08-25 23:21:57.036    1348-8771/? V/ActivityManager﹕ com.skibzy.skibzydesigns/.MessageActivity: task=TaskRecord{42ef8a28 #43 A com.skibzy.skibzydesigns U 0}
08-25 23:21:57.182    1348-1389/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '431744a8 com.skibzy.skibzydesigns/com.skibzy.skibzydesigns.MessageActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-25 23:21:57.183    1348-1389/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '431744a8 com.skibzy.skibzydesigns/com.skibzy.skibzydesigns.MessageActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-25 23:21:57.183    1348-1389/? W/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4343b398 com.skibzy.skibzydesigns/com.skibzy.skibzydesigns.MessageActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
08-25 23:21:57.184    1348-1389/? E/InputDispatcher﹕ channel '4343b398 com.skibzy.skibzydesigns/com.skibzy.skibzydesigns.MessageActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
08-25 23:21:57.195    1348-1363/? I/WindowState﹕ WIN DEATH: Window{4343b398 u0 com.skibzy.skibzydesigns/com.skibzy.skibzydesigns.MessageActivity}
```

Comment: There should be an error log on your server, which would indicate the cause of the 500 error message, and that would be a good place to start.

Comment: Sure thing, found it and it turns out my database credentials are being rejected. I have changed them and no difference. I have modified the php files from the classes used in the tutorial to a simple `mysql_connect()` and `mysql_select_db()` at the top of each php page. Could this be affecting its operations?

Comment: You are unnecessarily complicating matters. This is purely a PHP/mysql issue it has nothing at all to do with android or sqlite. Just figure out what data is being sent by your app to the server and then test the server in isolation using that data.

Comment: @Biko, don't use `mysql_` functions. Use `mysqli_` (I would suggest using the object oriented approach) or `PDO`. `mysql_` functions are deprecated and may pose security vulnerabilities. Also, I would suggest posting a new question about PHP and MySQL if you're unable to resolve the problem, because the issue you're having likely has nothing to do with Android.